# Escrever em um output de várias linhas no Javascript (documento que abre no navegador)

Tags: javascript, html5, navegador-de-internet

No javascript, tento rodar programas no navegador que fazem cálculos entre números e geram um output de várias linhas, mas ele deixa tudo em uma única linha quando executo o comando. Já tentei colocar o '\n' ao final de cada linha, tentei colocar o '\' e tentei concatenar, mas no output do navegador, fica tudo junto em uma única linha. Alguém saberia como resolver?

```
<script>
     var n1 = window.prompt('Digite um numero: ')
     var n2 = window.prompt('Digite outro numero: ')

     num1 = parseFloat(n1)
     num2 = parseFloat(n2)
     soma = num1 + num2

     document.write(`A soma dos números foi igual a ${soma}`)
     document.write('Muito obrigado')
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não se esqueça de que estamos falando de HTML, então para pular uma linha basta usar a Tag responsável para isto, que é a Tag `<br />`, ficando assim:

```
<script>
     var n1 = window.prompt('Digite um numero: ')
     var n2 = window.prompt('Digite outro numero: ')

     num1 = parseFloat(n1)
     num2 = parseFloat(n2)
     soma = num1 + num2

     document.write(`A soma dos números foi igual a ${soma}`)
     document.write('<br/>')
     document.write('Muito obrigado')
</script>
```